# Inner and outer join with three tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

Okey I'm trying to join some tables, but with no luck.
I manage to join them, but it shows duplicate!(?)

And as you can se in table two, column date, i want to sort the
result with that. But again, no luck with the following query:

```
SELECT traning.uid, traning.type, traning.duration, users.user_id, users.user_name,traning_type.type_id, traning_type.name
FROM traning
INNER JOIN users
ON traning.uid=users.user_id
INNER JOIN traning_type
ON traning.type=traning_type.type_id
```

Below follows the table layouts and columns i want to query.

```
table one users
----
user_id user_name


table two training
----
id uid type min_puls medel_puls max_puls duration date



table three traning_type
----
type_id name
```

uid in traning table is the user_id from users table, and type in training is type_id from traning_type.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Naruto Jsfiddle only used for javascrit, jquery, ajax...

Comment: you mean SQL Fiddle? ? :P

Comment: Apologies, I mean SQL-fiddle  (going to lose my head one of these days :) )

Comment: Sorry didn't even know about sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4f2d/1/0

Comment: have you tried select distinct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database diagram  isn't correct

## It should be :

```
        table one users
        ----
        user_id user_name


        associative table(user_training)
        user_id tr_id min_puls medel_puls max_puls duration date

        table two training
        ----
        tr_id  type_name
```

### And your Query should be :

```
SELECT training.type_name,users.user_id,users.user_name,
user_training.min_puls,user_training.medel_puls,user_training.max_puls,
user_training,duration, user_training.date
FROM training INNER JOIN user_training 
ON training.tr_id=user_training.tr_id
INNER JOIN users ON user_training.user_id=users.user_id
```

Comment: two rows still end up as four rows

Comment: try group by users.user_id